# Convert slope file to calculate the percentage of the coverage

Tags: arcmap, slope

I calculated the Slope of the area that I'm working on, and I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the actual percentage of each bracket, meaning the percentage of contribution of each class. The Slope is a floating point type of file and I cant convert it to polygon. Any advice could be helpful.

[image]

Comment: You need to convert it to an INTEGER raster using the Spatial Analysts tool `int()`. This will allow you to create an attribute table and then its a simple matter of looking at the count against number of cells with values.

Comment: I did as you said and it gave me a layer with an attribute table of 260 rows. :-/

Comment: Can you edit your question and show that, I would have expected 90 rows, 0 to 90 degrees. But you have learnt the lesson, to get counts of cells you need your raster to be an integer raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Reclassify tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) to reclassify your slope raster into the ranges you want. The Reclassify tool exists in ArcToolbox -> Spatial Analyst Tools -> Reclass -> Reclassify.

When you run the Reclassify tool, you need to rearrange the cell values as the following (*the original slope values may look different in your case*):

[image]

The output reclassified raster will as follows:

[image]

When you open the attribute table you will have three columns: OID, Value, and Count. Right-click the Count Column and go to Statistics:

[image]

Look at the sum, this is the total number of cells with values:

[image]

Copy the Sum value, then add a new column of type Double, name it Percent,and calculate the percentage of each class using Field Calculator:

[image]

[image]